# I am getting an response of 500 when trying to make an ajax call to rest service by passing the parameters

Tags: java

I have an html text box that takes the input and that input is passed to restful webservice through the ajax call.But I am getting an error of 500.

This is my service:

```java
@Path("/Reportees")
public class ReporteesService {
         ReporteeList   reportee = new ReporteeList();

     @GET
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
         public Map<Object, Object> getList(String empid) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("id is"+empid);
        Map<Object, Object> map=reportee.getReportees(empid);  //error in this line also
        Collection c=map.values();
        String value="";
        for (Iterator iterator = c.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
        {
            value = (String) iterator.next();
            Map<Object, Object> mapData=jiraservice.getJiras(value);
            System.out.println(value);

        }
        System.out.println("returning map");
        return map;             
    }

}
```

This is my resource:

```java
public class ReporteeList {
       public Map<Object, Object> getReportees(String idOfEmp) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(idOfEmp);
        String msg = "error";
        String api = "https://connect.ucern.com/api/core/v3/people/";
        String id = idOfEmp;
        String ext = "/@reports";
        String url = api + id + ext;
        String name = "*********";
        String password = "*********";
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
        Client restClient = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);
        ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept("application/json").header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
        if (resp.getStatus() != 200) {
            System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
        }
        String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);

        // JSONParser reads the data from string object and break each data into key
        // value pairs
        JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
        // Type caste the parsed json data in json object
        JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) parse.parse(output);
        // Store the JSON object in JSON array as objects (For level 1 array element i.e list)

        JSONArray jsonarr_s = (JSONArray) jobj.get("list");
        Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>(); //error in this line 

                if (jsonarr_s.size() > 0) {

            // Get data for List array
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr_s.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject) jsonarr_s.get(i);
            JSONObject jive = (JSONObject) jsonobj_1.get("jive");
                Object names = jsonobj_1.get("displayName");
        Object userid = jive.get("username");
                 map.put(names, userid);                  
            }

            return map;
        } else {
            map.put("errorcheck", msg);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

I am getting error message as:
 The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException

My ajax call:

```js
$(function() {
    var empid = document.getElementById("ManagerId").value;

    $('#submit').click(function(){ 
        $.ajax({ 
            crossDomain : true,
             type: "GET",
             dataType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:8088/JirasTrackingApp/reporter/Reportees?empid="+empid,

             success: function(result){        
                console.log(result);
                document.write(empid.value);
             }
         });
        });

    });
```

Stack trace:

```
id is
Base64 encoded auth string:*********
Unable to connect to the server

 Jan 22, 2019 10:23:51 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse     mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re- throwing    to the HTTP container
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.JiraTrackerApp.ReporteeList.getReportees(ReporteeList.java:48)
 at com.JiraTrackerApp.ReporteesService.getList(ReporteesService.java:33)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvok erFactory.java:60)
 at      com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatc hProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java :185)
at  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher. dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

 Jan 22, 2019 10:23:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve  invoke
  SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Webapp Application] in  context with path [/JirasTrackingApp] threw exception
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.JiraTrackerApp.ReporteeList.getReportees(ReporteeList.java:48)
  at com.JiraTrackerApp.ReporteesService.getList(ReporteesService.java:33)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where's the server stack trace?

Comment: Most exceptions eventually return a 500 code. Please share server logs.

Comment: Which is line 48 of `ReporteeList.java`?

Comment: `JSONArray jsonarr_s = (JSONArray) jobj.get("list"); if (jsonarr_s.size() > 0) {` Looks like `jsonarr_s` is `null` because there is no `"list"` entry in that JSON.